# Как воспроизвести видео один раз при появление в области просмотра экрана

Tags: reactjs, видео, setinterval, settimeout

Как сделать так, чтобы видео воспроизводилось один раз при появление в области видимости. У меня получается либо оно проигрывается бесконечно находясь в области видимости, если запускаю видео методом play(), либо проигрывается один раз при загрузке или обновление, если добавляю атрибуту autoPlay значение 'true', но в область видимости может не попасть. Пробовала отключить воспроизведение меняя src, но в консоли куча ошибок, например: "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request." и сайт очень сильно тормозит и другие анимации начинают работать некорректно.

```
  const isShouldAnimationAdvantageStart = () => {
    const animationAdvantage = document.getElementById('animation-advantage')
    const animationAdvantageCoords = animationAdvantage.getBoundingClientRect()
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight
      ? window.innerHeight
      : document.documentElement.clientHeight
      ? document.documentElement.clientHeight
      : document.body.offsetHeight
    return (
      animationAdvantageCoords.top > document.body.scrollTop &&
      animationAdvantageCoords.height + animationAdvantageCoords.top < document.body.scrollTop + windowHeight // animationAdvantage.clientHeight
    )
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const animationAdvantage = document.getElementById('animation-advantage')

    if (isShouldAnimationAdvantageStart()) {
      setStartAnimationAdvantage(true)
      animationAdvantage.play()
    }

    if (!isShouldAnimationAdvantageStart()) {
      setStartAnimationAdvantage(false)
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        animationAdvantage.src = ''
        setStartAnimationAdvantage(false)
      }, 3450)
    }, 3450)
  }, [isShouldAnimationAdvantageStart])

  return (<video
          muted
          autoPlay={startAnimationAdvantage}
          id='animation-advantage'
          width='555px'
          height='555px'
          poster={imageAdvantage}
        >
          <source src={videoAdvantage} type='video/mp4' />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
     )
```

Comment: Никогда не работал с видео, потому не буду писать как ответ, но если у вас получается отключить видео в необходимый момент, то можете вывести это событие в стейт isPlaying и обернуть элемент видео в паттерн проверки "return (isPlaying ? <video>...</video> : <SomethingBackground>)".

Comment: Отключить получается с помощью setTimeout и setInterval, как написано в коде, но с кучей ошибок в консоли и с зависанием сайта. Поэтому спрашиваю как это можно решить другим способом

Comment: А loop={false} не пробовали?

Comment: Пробовала не помогает. autoPlay работает как надо, но только если находишься в области просмотра. Не понимаю, почему так. Условие одни и те же что для метода play(), что для autoPlay

Comment: Так у вас юз эффект вызывает остановку видео после того, как вы выходите из этой области.

Comment: Так и должно быть.) Я так и хотела

Comment: Тогда не понимаю, что вас удивляет.

Comment: То что если я вначале страницы и доскроллила до нужного видео оно должно воспроизводиться. С play() так и происходит, но видео повторяется. Если убрать play() и оставить только autoPlay и добавлять ему true, то работает только когда изначально находишься в области просмотра, если находишься в начале страницы и потом доходишь до видео, то видео не воспроизводиться. Я это все описывала выше

Comment: Я могу вам предложить только рендерить блок с видео после того, как вы доскроллите до нужного места на основе того же стейта. Т.е. когда компонент отрендерится, запустится автоплей и с параметром loop={false} оно проиграется один раз. Как только элемент пропадет из экрана, компонент размонтируется. Также можно поискать какие нибудь либы для реакта, возможно там найдется функционал поинтересней.

Comment: loop={false} не помогает вообще

Comment: До меня только сейчас дошло, вы же используете пропсы этой библиотеки https://video-react.js.org/components/player/ Но вы не использовали компонент этой библиотеки. Вам нужно заменить тег <video>, на <Player>. Я открыл документации по этому пакету и там есть все нужные вам пропсы.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Решила вопрос, нужно было поставить preload='none', а при  достижение видео setAttribute('preload', true), и все заработало как надо.